# What is the difference between a UDP endpoint and a UDP client?

Tags: udp

In simple words, what is the difference? Is it same as a server (the end point). Is it the same as transparent UDP? Please clear it for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

None. UDP isn't really a client-server protocol, so 'endpoint' is a better term than 'client'.

Comment: Thanks. Also, is there any difference between a UDP Socket and transparent UDP Socket?

Comment: I don't know what a 'transparent UDP socket' is. Where did you get the term from?

Comment: It was there in one of the documentation for the board I'm working on. Transparent TCP and UDP.